# How to concat and update at the same time while using a where clause?

Tags: mysql

`update discountLinks set tag=concat(tag, '-on') where free_trial_period_month is not null;`

I am getting an Unknown column error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your syntaxs is correct, one of the `tag` or the `free_trial_period_month` column probably does not exist in the table `discountLinks`

Comment: Yeah, it was `free_trial_month_period`